# Contents imported from csv file goes beyond the page below

Tags: geometry, datatool, csv, import, excel2latex

I want to create a one-word Q&A document. I imported the contents from a .csv file which has 104 rows, the contents go below the page and not to the next page. How do I rectify it?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{array}
\DTLloadrawdb[keys={col1,col2}]{data}{Unit6.csv}
\renewcommand{\dtlstringformat}[1]{\begin{varwidth}[t]{8cm}#1\end{varwidth}}

\setmainlanguage{tamil}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily{\tamilfont}[Script=Tamil,Scale=1]{Meera Inimai}
\title{10ஆம் வகுப்பு - வேதியியல் - இயல் 6}
\author{சீனிவாசன்}
\date{30-09-2022}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\DTLdisplaydb{data}
\end{document}
```

[image: Going beyond page continuously]

Comment: load longtable and use `\DTLdisplaylongdb`, see the documentation of datatool.

Comment: thanks, it works.